# How to call VB.NET from F#?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, f#

In my program, I have a Visual Basic (.NET) form for user interface,
I store all user inputs to an object called Input. 
How can I get that Input object from F# , given that I have F# and VB.NET projects
in the same visual studio 2010 solution ?

Comment: Add a reference to the VB project in the F# in VS

Comment: If the UI is your VB.net project chances are high that you want your F# code in the UI and not the other way around - anyway it's as @JohnPalmer said just the same as with any other .net assembly in VS - youse add refrence ;)

Comment: that's right, I should really use F# functions in VB. Not the other way around. But F# functions would require some types defined in VB project. For example, F# would need, in this case, the "InputClass" type. On the other hand, VB project would require reference to F# to get back the results and display them. And therefore, these are circular references which are not allowed. The only way (that I know) is define all common type for both Projects in a third project or a DLL. But it seems a bit complicated for something that should be simple.

Comment: @N.T.C: You are right, your InputClass should either live in the F# project, or if you want to keep it VB, in a separate VB project. The situation would be the same if you had two VB projects instead - either you'd need a third project for the common parts, or you'd move the common parts to the upstream project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F# Project -> Reference -> AddReference and select your dll(exe)

F# code

open YourNamespace

Use your vb.net functions.